# Displaying html form inputs on browser permanently after fetched from MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have used an isset() function on 'submit' to store and retrieve my html form inputs. However all my SQL data in my table only gets displayed after I clicked the submit function on the browser as I programmed it that way.

I would like to make it now so that even when I refresh the browser the html form input remains permanently and I do not have to click submit to fetch the entire table and display (it rather displays itself straight away).

Please show me how I can go about this?

below is my code:

```html
<?php

require_once "connection.php";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {


 $question = $_POST['question'];
 $description = $_POST['description'];

 $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME );

 if($conn->connect_error) {

  die("connection error: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } else {

  echo "Submit button connected to database!";
 }

 }


 if(isset($_POST['question']) && $_POST['description']) {

 $sql = " INSERT INTO `ask` (question_id, question, description) VALUES
 (NULL, '{$question}', '{$description}' ) ";

 if($conn->query($sql)) {

  echo "it worked";
 } else {

  echo "error: " . $conn->error;

  exit();
 }


 $query = "SELECT * FROM `ask` ";

  $result = $conn->query($query);

 
      
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<p> {$row['question']}</p>";
            echo "<p> {$row['description']}</p>";
        }
 

$conn->close();



}






?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>



<div id="submitQuestion">

 <form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="question"/>
  <textarea name="description" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ASK"/>
 </form>

</div>









</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You already oppened an issue about the same code... Why are you posting again

Comment: Since your table may have more entries, you should specify what do you want to show inside inputs. Do you want to show the last inserted value?

Comment: I want to display all entries in the display which is why i have SELECT * FROM `ask` and the code works...just however when I refresh the browser all my data goes missing and only when I click the submit button after filling in the form all the data gets fetched again..I want to make it so that upon refresh data remains in browser permanently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've correctly understood the question, you would like to always display all entries and add new data only when it's required. For this goal, you can connect and retrieve data independently from form submission, and insert new data only when required.

```
<?php

require_once "connection.php";

// Connect to database
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME );

if($conn->connect_error) {
    die("connection error: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Insert new data if required
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['question']) && isset($_POST['description'])) 
{
    $question = $_POST['question'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    $sql = " INSERT INTO `ask` (question_id, question, description) VALUES
        (NULL, '{$question}', '{$description}' ) ";

    if(!$conn->query($sql)) {
        echo "error during insert: " . $conn->error;
        exit();
    }
}

// Display data
$query = "SELECT * FROM `ask` ";
$result = $conn->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<p> {$row['question']}</p>";
    echo "<p> {$row['description']}</p>";
}

// Close database connection        
$conn->close();

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div id="submitQuestion">

    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="question"/>
        <textarea name="description" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ASK"/>
    </form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're welcome. As a side note, I suggest you to make some validation and filtering on inputs after submission (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php).

Comment: Yes, will do for sure !

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

require_once "connection.php";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {


    $question = $_POST['question'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME );

    if($conn->connect_error) {

        die("connection error: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } else {

        echo "Submit button connected to database!";
    }

    }


    if(isset($_POST['question']) && $_POST['description']) {

    $sql = " INSERT INTO `ask` (question_id, question, description) VALUES
    (NULL, '{$question}', '{$description}' ) ";

    if($conn->query($sql)) {

        echo "it worked";
    } else {

        echo "error: " . $conn->error;

        exit();
    }

}
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `ask` ";

     $result = $conn->query($query);



        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<p> {$row['question']}</p>";
            echo "<p> {$row['description']}</p>";
        }


$conn->close();   



?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>



<div id="submitQuestion">

    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="question"/>
        <textarea name="description" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ASK"/>
    </form>

</div>
```

As I told you in the other question..

Comment: I took away the if() condition but the data does not display when I refresh my browser. Sorry, I just did not want to bother you anymore as you helped me plenty....